# Calculating datediff in days on Python / SQL Server / Stata

Tags: python, sql-server, stata

[image]

I want to create a new column called days that calculate the date difference for each distinct users.

For example, days for distinct user x1 starting from minimum date of x1, days would look like ..

days = 1, 2,3,4,5,6,...

What is the best way to do this for every distinct user in the data?

Each distinct users have different length of dates in the data set as shown in the picture.

Any solutions using SQL Server, Python, or Stata?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python and SQL are completely different languages... What's wrong, however, with `DATEDIFF` is SQL? It's even in your title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Stata solution, assuming you would be importing the dates as strings:

```
* GENERATE SAMPLE DATA
    clear
    set obs 2
    gen user_i = _n
    expand 10
    gen month = runiformint(1,12)
    gen day = runiformint(1,28) if inlist(month,2)
    replace day = runiformint(1,31) if inlist(month,1,3,5,7,8,10,12)
    replace day = runiformint(1,30) if mi(day)
    gen e_date = "2019" + "-" + (2 - strlen(string(month)))*"0" + string(month) + "-" + (2 - strlen(string(day)))*"0" + string(day)
    drop month day

* calculate days
    gen date = date(e_date, "YMD")
    format date %td
    bysort user_i (date): gen days_from_min = date-date[1]
```

that being said, there is most certainly a way to do this quite easily in MSSQL or wherever your data is currently housed.

Comment: Oh my lord sir, you've just saved my day :) thanks a lot I really appreciate it

Comment: Excellent! So depending on how your data is read into Stata, the only line that matters is the final one.